# MPhils or Masters by Research in Germany in a mathematical subject

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, masters, germany

I was wondering whether there are Masters by Research or MPhils in Germany in a mathematical subject? I have been advised to look at the 3 Berlin universities (TU, HU, FU) but have only found PhD's and MSc's. What is the equivalent of a research masters in Germany? Thanks!

Comment: Are you quite sure that these MSc degrees you found are not research based? That does not agree with my experience of Masters-level degrees in Germany. Some links to the information you found could be helpful.

Comment: I don't think the distinction between MPhil and MSc is that well established in Germany (the Master title is pretty new there). So you need to look at the content of the program rather than the title to find out whether it is research focused or not.

Comment: An MSc *is* an integrated research master (i.e., completed by writing a Masters thesis) in Germany. Although the alternative (a non-thesis Master) is possible by law, to the best of my knowledge this isn't offered by any university in Germany (technical or otherwise; note that universities of applied science (*Fachhochschulen*) are different). The possibility of a third-stage thesis-only Masters is not provided for under the German system.

Comment: Although what you could do, if you already have a non-thesis Master degree, is enrol in an MSc degree and get your coursework in the non-thesis degree recognized towards the MSc -- if everything lines up perfectly (which it never will...), you'd only have to write the thesis to obtain the MSc.

Answer (score 2):

Most master’s degrees in Germany require a thesis in some form, usually comprising the final semester of studies. However, because of the Bologna process, there are unlikely to be “pure research” programs.